# Symfony 4 throwing UndefinedMethodException exception

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've been having this weird issue since today. I'm currently working on a system that uses Symfony 4 as its base. Locally, it works perfectly, no problemas whatsoever. However, when I push the code to Azure (where I'm going to deploy and serve it when its done), I get the following errors on my prod.log:

```
[2018-11-28 19:19:26] php.CRITICAL: Call to undefined method Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PhpParser::write() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\PhpParser::write() at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Session\\Storage\\Handler\\StrictSessionHandler.php:64)"} []
[2018-11-28 19:19:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "write" of class "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PhpParser"." at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler.php line 64 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\UndefinedMethodException(code: 0): Attempted to call an undefined method named \"write\" of class \"Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\PhpParser\". at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Session\\Storage\\Handler\\StrictSessionHandler.php:64)"} []
```

I've cleared composer cache, Symfony cache, deleted the whole `vendor` directory and ran `composer update` (twice) hoping that it would fix the issue.

Other than changes in my code, I haven't changed anything else. I've searched everywhere about this `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PhpParser` package, but I can't find anything really related to it. Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "^7.2",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "^1.6",
        "box/spout": "^2.7",
        "nikic/php-parser": "^4.1",
        "piwik/device-detector": "^3.11",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.9",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "4.1.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Could this be a issue with some of the required packages?

Comment: You don't have doctrine in your composer json. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: Can you post your local composer.json ?

Comment: Can you check if your issue is the same as https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29365? In this case, downgrading `symfony/debug` to 4.1.7 would be the solution for now until 4.1.9 is released.

Comment: Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PhpParser is part of doctrine/common package. You can install it as standalone or with symfony/orm-pack

Comment: @EquaPro as far as I can tell, the required Doctrine packages are installed by symfony/maker-bundle. SInce I'm only using them in the dev environment, they shouldn't cause issues when running in prod environment. I'll try installing the symfony/orm-pack you said to see if it fix those issues.

Comment: @YoannMir that is my local composer.json, it is the very same that is deployed on Azure.

Comment: @xabbuh doesn't seems to be my case. I did what EquaPro said and installed symfony/orm-pack. Now it is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing a package. @EquaPro pointed out in the comments that `PhpParser` is a part of `doctrine/common` package, which isn't installed by any of the packages I have in my `composer.json`.

Possible reasons: when I was following the Security/Authentication tutorial, I decided to not install Doctrine since I wasn't going to use it.Fixed it by installing `symfony/orm-pack`.